# Angular - How to style material table the right way

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a simple mat table:

```html
<div class="tableEnclosing">
    <mat-table class="mat-elevation-z8" [dataSource]="dataSource">
      
        <ng-container matColumnDef="id" matSort>
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>#</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let item;">{{item.id}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
      
        <ng-container matColumnDef="name" matSort>
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Name</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell  *matCellDef="let item;">{{item.name}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        
        <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
        <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></mat-row>
        
    </mat-table>
</div>
```

I am trying to set the width of this table to 50%.

I can easily access this table from my scss file like this:

```css
.mat-mdc-table {
    width: 50%;
    background: red;
}
```

The background is set correctly, but width doesn't do anything, the table is still 100%. Some people have said that encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None will do the trick but it seems not recommended. Setting the `.tableEnclosing {width: 50%}` also does the trick but this seems weird as well.

So is there a better way of styling mat-table? Is the solution something that applies to all mat components? The only width styling I could find was styling the width of the columns, nothing about the actual table itself.

Versions:

```json
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.1.0",
"@angular/cli": "^17.1.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.1.0",
"@angular/material": "^17.1.2",
"typescript": "~5.3.2"
```

I tried:

```css
table {
   width: 50%;
}

.mat-mdc-table {
   width: 50%;
}
```

Expected:
the table at 50% width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `::ng-deep` to access elements without the need for setting viewEncapsulation to none. Prepend it with `:host` to avoid style conflicts with other components

```
:host ::ng-deep {
    .mat-mdc-table {
        width: 50%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can wrap the table on a `div` and set the style to `width:50%` this will set the width of the grid!

```
<div style="width: 50%">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
        The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>No.</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.position}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.name}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Weight Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Weight</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.weight}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Symbol Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Symbol</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.symbol}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/kpik4c?file=src%2Fexample%2Ftable-basic-example.html)

Comment: Yeah, I tried that- that's the `<div class="tableEnclosing">`  I talked about. It works, but I was wondering if that is the best option.